# Efficient algorithm of rank-one update of the Cholesky decomposition

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

Suppose that I have a symmetric positive definite matrix $X$ and that I Cholesky-decompose it

$$ X = L L^T $$

Now, given a vector $v$, suppose we want to decompose the following matrix using the Cholesky decomposition:

$$ X + v v^T = M M^T $$

I know the complexity of the Cholesky decomposition is $O(n^3)$. Is there a algorithm to compute $M$ given $X$, $L$, $v$, that has a complexity less than $O(n^3)$?

Comment: I read too quickly to be sure, but I think this resource https://christian-igel.github.io/paper/AMERCMAUfES.pdf describes a $O(n^2)$ update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow uses the implementation recorded in Krause & Igel (2015).

reference:
Krause, O., & Igel, C. (2015, January). A more efficient rank-one covariance matrix update for evolution strategies. In Proceedings of the 2015 ACM Conference on Foundations of Genetic Algorithms XIII (pp. 129-136).

Comment: Nice, it looks like they did an algorithm in O(n)